# Service becomes undefined in exception handler

Tags: angular, angular6, servicestack

I have a service that injects my `AuthenticationService`.  In this service I initiate a third party typescript client and register a method inside the service as the exception handler.

My issue is that when the exception handler gets called the `AuthenticationService` has become undefined.  I set breakpoint in constructor and can see the `_auth` variable is populated properly.  But when exception handler gets called it is undefined.  I tried setting it as a property but same behaviour occurs.

This is my service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DomainAlertsService {
  client : JsonServiceClient;

  constructor( private _auth: AuthenticationService ) { 
    this.client = new JsonServiceClient(environment.apiUrl);
    this.client.exceptionFilter = this.exceptionHandler;
  }

  exceptionHandler(ex : Response)
  {
    if(ex.status == 401)
    {
        this._auth.logout(); // _auth is now undefined
        location.reload(true);
    }
    else{
      console.log("unhandled exception");
      console.log(ex);
    }

  }

  //.. other methods removed

}
```

I imagine this is some sort of scoping issue but I am not sure what is going on.  Why is `_auth` undefined when `exceptionHandler()` method called?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to bind it to the scope of the component, like so:

```
this.client.exceptionFilter = this.exceptionHandler.bind(this);
```

Comment: Thanks, this work.  I will accept answer after time limit.